# Условие в заполнении БД SQL

Tags: sql

Никак не могу придумать, как обойти такую вещь: если [[@a](/users/48/asmer)](/users/48/asmer)>1 и [[@a](/users/48/asmer)](/users/48/asmer)<10, то [[[@b](/users/91/boh)](/users/91/boh)](/users/91/boh)=1 или [[[@b](/users/91/boh)](/users/91/boh)](/users/91/boh)=2...т.е. как для одного и того же условия сделать так, чтобы присваивалось разное значение? как-то OR уже здесь нельзя сделать?

```
if @а>1 and @а<=10 set @b=1
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен. Расскажите лучше, чего именно вы хотите добиться на более высоком уровне. Прямо сейчас ваша задача кажется противоречивой (`@b` уж либо 1, либо 2, третьего не дано), может быть, я неправильно её понял?

Comment: при выполнении условия вы хотите присвоить `@b` случайно выбранное значение из набора `(1, 2)` ?

Comment: да, чтобы значение переменной присваивалось случайно из двух, грубо говоря
 if @а>1 and @а<=10 set @b=1 OR @b=2

Comment: Вы OR как-то не так понимаете. OR это булева операция, которая возвращает TRUE, если хотя бы один из операндов равен TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if @a>1 and @a<=10 
    set @b = Cast(2* Rand() + 1 As tinyint)
```

Comment: не в смысле рандома я имею ввиду, а если текстовые значения допустим? if @a>1 and @a<=10, то атрибут принимает значение ААА или БББ

Comment: @wicS: а кто будет решать, как не вы, программист, _какое именно_ из ААА и БББ?

Comment: Так:
    
    if @a>1 and @a<=10 begin
        set @rnd = Cast(2* Rand() + 1 As tinyint)
        if @rnd = 1
            set @b = 'AAA'
        else
            set @b = 'БББ'
    end

Comment: спасибо, применимо к моему примеру работает) а можете пояснить, как @rnd считается? cast же по сути преобразовывает тип данных?

Comment: `Cast` здесь для приведения к целочисленному типу. Т.к. `Rand()` генерирует число с плавающей точкой в интервале от `0` до `1`.